# get list of projects within solution from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-generation

I implemented the `IWizard`-interface from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard` to generate a VS-project-file automatically. Within my solution there are four different projects.

Now within `ProjectFinishedGenerating` I want to get a list of all projects within my solution:

```
public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
{
    var vsProject = (VSProject)project.Object;
    var references = ((Array)project.DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects).OfType<Project>();
}
```

However only the project indicated by that one provided to the method is returned instead of all projects within the solution. Of course the projects are all active.

[image: ListOfProjectsInSolution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously `DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects` returns a list of the *selected* projects. What we want instead is a list of all the *active* ones:

```
var references = project.DTE.Solution.Projects.Cast<Project>();
```